# Committing to git without knowning the whole history

Tags: git

We have a fairly large git repository to which we do automatic commits.

Is it possible to commit to a git repository without downloading the hole history first?
In my opinion it should be, since the current commit just references the last one, but I don't know how.

Comment: When you clone a Git repo you typically clone the entire thing.  What is your aversion to doing this?

Comment: The size of the repository. It currently contains about 10 GiB of commits and we just clone the repository to do one commit and then purge the clone. We cannot persist the clone since the environment is ephemeral (docker container spawned by jenkins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep you can do it.

```
# clone specific branch and only latest commit 
# This will only download a single branch and you will not be able to 
# see other branches

git clone <url> --branch=<branch> --depth=1
```

---

## Git clone options:

#### `-b / --branch`

Download **only** a specific branch
`--branch` can also take **tags** and **detaches the HEAD** at that commit
in the resulting repository.

---

#### `--depth`

How many commits (latest) to download.
Create a shallow clone with a history truncated to the specified number of commits.

---

#### `--shallow-since=<date>`

Create a shallow clone with a history after the specified time.

You can also checkout any **past** commit form history and not only the latest

Comment: Wow I was actually aware of this option but assumed I cannot commit to such a repository. I just tested it and it works without problems! Thanks very much, I'll accept this answer as soon as stackoverflow will allow me

Comment: When you commit git link the commit to the previous log entry. you don't need to have the whole tree in order to be able to commit. You can also checkout any **past** commit form history and not only the latest